# Installing "duplicate" on SSH /home/user

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure, non-root-user

I am on a SSH server and want to use a program that is at /usr/local/bin but I don't have permission.
So I copied the program installation files from my system to my user on the server in order to install it at /home/user.It is probably a different release of the program than the one installed at /usr/local/bin.
Is there a possibility that I screw up the way the already installed program works?I'm guessing not,because I am not the administrator so it would stop me from messing something up.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that you can screw up the existing installation. No locally "installed" program will be setuid, so it will run with your permissions, meaning that it can't do anything you can't do with other programs.

But if you just copy the binaries from your own system, they might not work as intended. Worst case is that it doesn't work at all (would e.g. be the case if the architectures are different) more likely it will depend on some library that isn't an appropriate version. The best way to get a program that will work, is to compile it yourself, and as a part of that configure it to use local versions of all libraries that you need and can't rely on being (and remaining) in a good version on the system, of course you will probably need to compile a lot of libraries yourself.

In short: You need to be really sure before you start this, because it quickly becomes a huge project. Have you tried asking the administrator if they could change the permissions so you can use the installed version?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Admin/Sudoer access, the likelyhood of you breaking your system (for all users) is probably fairly slim, then again, it's possible that your system has been customized as such to allow a non-sudoer to install programs, or make other harmful modifications. It's also possible, that installing a duplicate for only your local user could cause problems for just your profile.

My best advice would be to proceed with caution, and keep track of your changes in the event you need to back them out. If you're worried about breaking the system for other users/user profiles, you're probably not going to do so. The community may be able to provide more clarity with a more detailed question eg: What distro? Have many modifications to the system been made? What application are you trying to install... etc.